# delete an object after meeting condition

Tags: javascript

I want to delete an object called bossOne, that is made on the bases of my class BossOne.

It should be done sth like:

```
let bossOne;
bossOne = new BossOne();

if(true) {
delete bossOne;
}
```

My class:

```
class BossOne {
    constructor() {
        this.x = canvas.width/2 - canvas.width/6;
        this.y = 200;
        this.sizeX = canvas.width/3;
        this.sizeY = canvas.width/14;
        this.speed = 3;
    }

    show() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.sizeX, this.sizeY);
    }

    changeDirection() {
        this.speed *= -1;
    }

    move() {
        this.x += this.speed;
    }
}
```

Main code:

```
let bossOne;
bossOne = new BossOne();

function draw() {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    bossOne.show();
    bossOne.move();
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

I could place the object into an array and use splice to clean it, but is there a better way without array? 
Thank you for your tips :)

Comment: what is the condition for removal?

Comment: If you want to delete the object you need to attach it to the window (or some other object) `window.bossOne = new BossOne()`, then you can delete it with `delete window.bossOne`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot delete an object in JavaScript because there is a garbage collector in it which do it automatically for you. you can just tag an object for collection with setting it to `null` or `undefined`. GC will remove it if there is not any other references for that object in your program.

Comment: That's really good point. It's working well. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't actually care about *removing* the object itself (Javascript's garbage collection will automatically take care of that once the object isn't being accessed anymore), but rather wish to stop rendering BossOne.

I'd do this by adding a `hide` function, which should do something along these lines:

```js
ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.sizeX, this.sizeY);
```

And then add a flag to make sure it doesn't get re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `delete` on an item, it must be attached to an object, then you can delete it from that object.

In this example I attach the class to the window:

```js
class A {}

window.a = new A

console.log(window.a)

delete window.a

console.log(window.a)
```

If we attach the value to `let` or `var`, the value doesn't get deleted, however, setting the value to `undefined` will allow the garbage collector to take care of it, as you can see in this example:

```js
class A {}

let a = new A

console.log(a)

delete a

console.log(a)

// The garbage collector will take of it now
a = undefined

console.log(a)
```